# How to place line underneath the circle? without z-index

Tags: css

I made an X with a circle using css.

There is a green line that is sticking out on top of the circle, how do I place it under the circle?

How would this be done?

code: https://jsfiddle.net/6wod3pLm/

That is all I am doing in the code.

[image]

```css
.exitnew {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.exitnew:before,
.exitnew:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  top: 22px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.exitnew:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exitnew:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.exitnew:hover:before,
.exitnew:hover:after {
  background: green;
}

.exitnew b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="exitnew" type="button" aria-label="Close"><b></b></button>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using z-index? Also is there a reason for using the extra HTML element (b)?

Comment: How would <b></b> be removed from the code?

Comment: Using gradients.

Comment: How would it be written using a gradient?

Comment: You would use several, see the answer from @TemaniAfif - this is particularly good because it doesn't clutter your HTML with elements that have no particular semantics attached to them - doing it just in CSS separates the styling from the meaning. Good for accessibility too.

Comment: How would it be written without calc? Can it be written without calc? Using several gradients, how would it be written? Assuming that is how it would be done without calc.

Comment: Just substitute the actual values and do the arithmetic yourself in advance. But the point of using calc is that you only have to define things in one place - makes maintainability much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all these code. Here is an easier idea:

```css
.exitnew {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  --b:7px;                /* the thickness*/
  --c:blue 90deg,green 0; /* the coloration */
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),var(--c)) 
    calc(100% + var(--b)/2) calc(100% + var(--b)/2)/
    calc(50%  + var(--b))   calc(50%  + var(--b));
  border: 5px solid red;;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="exitnew" type="button" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Comment: How would it be written without calc? Can you show an example of that?

Comment: @htmlcssjava321 why I have to write it without calc ?

Comment: I wanted to see how it would be written without calc because calc is not something I use a lot in code.

Comment: @htmlcssjava321 you can wait for more answers, I don't really want to drop calc() and do  all the calculation manually. By the way, this is a good time to start using calc(). Don't get afraid by new features

Answer (score 1):

:before and :after are like html bread on you element sandwich. :before is the bottom slice, and :after is the top slice.

Add a negative z-index to the :before, :after styles and that will position your :after behind the button the same as the :before.

```
.exitnew:before,
.exitnew:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  top: 22px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

EDIT WITHOUT Z-INDEX

```css
.exitnew {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.exitnew:before,
.exitnew:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 38px;
  top: 22px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.exitnew:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exitnew:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.exitnew:hover:before,
.exitnew:hover:after {
  background: green;
}

.exitnew b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="exitnew" type="button" aria-label="Close"><b></b></button>
```

Comment: How would it be written without z-index?

Comment: Without z-index (not sure why you can't use it) you could make your before and after items smaller and position them differently... { width: 38px; top: 22px; left: 5px; right: 5px; }

Comment: Without z-index is not working here: https://jsfiddle.net/hwrxjapk/ Are you sure that is right?

Comment: Fixed and added to snippet.

Comment: I added hover to the X here, how do I remove <b> </b> from it? https://jsfiddle.net/jqzs6d3o/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `z-index` property on the `:after` CSS selector:

```css
.exitnew {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.exitnew:before,
.exitnew:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  top: 22px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: -1
}

.exitnew:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exitnew:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.exitnew:hover:before,
.exitnew:hover:after {
  background: green;
}

.exitnew b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="exitnew" type="button" aria-label="Close"><b></b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `z-index` property to send the green line(s) backward, "behind" the circle:

```
.exitnew:before,
.exitnew:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  top: 22px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/q7zprh4w/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without `b` and `z-index`:

```
.exitnew {
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
} 

.exitnew::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10.416%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 44.792%;
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exitnew::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10.416%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 44.792%;
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I put the red border to the button itself. So the two pseudo element `::before` and `::after` aren't overlapping the red border.

Note: I don't use `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: I added hover to the X here, how do I remove <b> </b> from it? https://jsfiddle.net/jqzs6d3o/

Comment: How would I be able to edit that fiddle removing the <b> </b> tags from it?